# Using REST API in SharePoint forms in Office 365 using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, rest

Can someone direct me to some basic tutorial or component that would allow me to consume a REST API from SharePoint forms in Office 365. I would prefer to do all the customization using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: You may try to use `[WebRequest](https://community.nintex.com/community/tech-blog/blog/2015/08/07/nintex-forms-enterprise-web-request-control)` component.Go through https://community.nintex.com/community/tech-blog/blog/2015/08/07/nintex-forms-enterprise-web-request-control